# KQL :: How to Join Resources and AzureActivity

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

I found a list of [KQL queries](https://github.com/scautomation/AzureResourceGraph-Examples/blob/master/resourceQueries/Orphaned%20Resources/OrphanedResource.MD) that are helping me digging into unused resources on Azure.

With this query for example I can see a list of Orphaned Disks:

```
Resources
| where type has "microsoft.compute/disks"
| extend diskState = tostring(properties.diskState)
| where managedBy == "" and diskState != 'ActiveSAS'
or diskState == 'Unattached' and diskState != 'ActiveSAS'
| project id, diskState, resourceGroup, location, subscriptionId
```

which nicely render into this:

[image]

But I would like to add 3 more columns to it:

- Who created the resource
- When the resource was created
- Ideally how much it cost that resource in the last 30 days

I see that I probably have to [Join AzureActivity](http://blog.itaysk.com/2017/06/25/determine-who-created-resources-in-azure) in order to find who created the resource.

I still have no idea if KQL can help me find the costs per activity.

Comment: While both services use Azure Data Explorer (AKA ADX / Kusto) as a back end, and therefore support KQL, these are two different services, and they cannot be queried together.

Comment: Cool, should I delete my question? Of maybe you can post that comment as a valid reply

Comment: You can keep it As Is. I don't like posting "No, you can't" as an answer :-)